# Gateway function missing -->Matlab 2018a -->Mex

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to access C++ code from Matlab R2018a but getting error

```
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\\C++ForMatlab\test.mexw64': Gateway function is
missing.
```

I did the similar thing on Windows 7 with VS2013 and Matlab 2016 and it all worked fine.

The function compiles successfully and dll is created as expected but when I try to run it  I got error message.

**OS -->** Windows 10

**Matlab -->** Matlab R2018a

**C++ ->** VS 2017

Sample code written in VS2017

**FileName** --> test.cpp

```
 #include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mexPrintf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

In Matlab 
I type following command

```
 mex test.cpp
```

And Output I get is

```
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017'.
MEX completed successfully.
```

But After that when I try to run by typing

```
Trial>> test
```

I get following error

```
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\C++ForMatlab\test.mexw64': Gateway function is
missing
```

.

Comment: It looks like you're doing everything right. There might be an issue with your installation of MATLAB or of MSVC? Maybe the `mex.h` file found is not the right one? Try `mex -v text.cpp`, this will show you the actual compiler and linker commands executed. That might help you spot issues (e.g. wrong directories).

Comment: @CrisLuengo , I tried mex -v  and I cannot see any error in it. Output mentions building with Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 and  further it says creating library test.lib and object test.exp  and I successfully got executable

Comment: If all the paths there seem OK (e.g. pointing to your current MATLAB installation, not some old one) then there’s nothing I can do to help. Just make sure there is no `mex.h` file where except in your MATLAB distribution. Do contact your MATLAB representative or submit a ticket to their site if you’re a paying customer.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same mex routine that you just compiled? E.g., are you in the same directory etc.? What do you get when you type "which test" at the command line?

Comment: If you inspect the generated test.mexw64 with a tool like Dependency Walker, or dumpbin from a visual studio console, what do you see as exported symbol? Is there a decorated name like Z11mexFunctionBlaBlaFooBar...?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a file "ThisModule.def" and add following lines.(swap templateSFunc with your own file name)

LIBRARY "templateSFunc.mexw64"
EXPORTS
mexFunction

Then go to project properties in VS and add ThisModule.def to the linker/Input/Module Definition File option.

Comment: OP has no VS project, they’re using the `mex` command in MATLAB to build.